# How to get user's Facebook ID without any authentications?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have a little Facebook page tab app (subscribe form), where the user can enter his email address and name and then submit the form. All I want from Facebook API is, to get the logged in user's Facebook ID, so I can check if the user is already regged or not. I believe for this I don't need any permissions, or authentication dialogs to show, but I can't get any valid sessions for the Facebook ID query :( 
This is my code right now (the Javascript redirect was only for testing):

```
<?php 
session_start();

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookHttpable.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurl.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/Entities/AccessToken.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/Entities/SignedRequest.php');
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSignedRequestFromInputHelper.php');
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookCanvasLoginHelper.php');
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookOtherException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphObject.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphUser.php');
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphSessionInfo.php' );

use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurl;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;
use Facebook\Entities\SignedRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookSignedRequestFromInputHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\Helpers\FacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookOtherException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\GraphSessionInfo;

$appId = '123456789';
$appSecret = 'secret123456789';

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($appId , $appSecret);

$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper("https://www.facebook.com/mypage/app_123456789", $appId, $appSecret);
try {
    $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
}
catch(FacebookRequestException $ex) { } 
catch(\Exception $ex) { }

$loggedIn = false;

if (isset($session)){
if ($session) {
    $loggedIn = true;
    try {
      // Logged in

    } catch(FacebookRequestException $e) {

        echo "Exception occured, code: " . $e->getCode();
        echo " with message: " . $e->getMessage();

    }   

}
}
if (!$loggedIn){
  $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl();
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">top.location.href = "'.$loginUrl .'";</script>';
}

echo "session: ".$session; //empty
```

This Facebook PHP SDK V4 is a little bit new to me, can someone help me out how to correctly set it up, to get the users ID?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

**You ALWAYS need to authorize a user in order to get his ID. And it will be an "App Scoped ID". You can NOT get his ID only by using his email.**

Not sure what you mean with "regged"...do you mean "registered"? If you want the user to put in an email and check if he uses your platform already, why not just forget about Facebook and see if he is in the database with that email? You don´t need to use the Facebook API for that. Of course you need to store users with their email when they authorize your App, but that should be no problem.

Also, you should use the autoloader instead of countless require statements, but that´s just a side note.

Comment: I think you understood something different. This is a page tab app. If the user loads the app it will get his Facebook ID and check if he's already registered or not. If not the form will be visible, if yes he will only get a "thank you for registering" label. I don't want to use authorization for this, because that will scare the users away.

Comment: i do understand. the first paragraph of my answer is important, you do NOT get any id without authorization. not even in a page app. no id without authorization, that is a fact.